# Is it possible to create a single url from multiple values in multiple tables?

Tags: php

is it possible in php to create a single url from multiple values across multiple tables? 
For example, I want to generate a url that looks like the following:
http://www.domain.foo/joseph&soap&engineer&english, with the first name and surname is read from the NAMES table and occupation is read from the JOBS table and language is read from the SPEAKS table..?

Not sure if this is yet the correct way to solve my task, but thought I'd ask the question before I spend more time on it.

Comment: You URL is not working. And yes you can do it, just join all the tables from where you want to fetch the data.

Comment: Yes it is possible https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

That isn't the way url parameters work.  They should be name value pairs.  You are also missing the query string.  So what a normal url would look like would be this:

```
http://www.domain.foo/index.php?firstname=joseph&surname=soap&job=engineer&language=english
```

This is how you should be thinking about and approaching the use of the GET method and the passing of url parameters.  Often this gets confused with URL rewriting, which converts url's that omit script names and parameters but you should start with the basic functionality and worry about layering on url rewriting once your code is working.

The other thing you might be missing is the "routing" that comes with pretty much every framework that implements the MVC pattern.

For example, consider route to be an additional parameter that gets passed as `route=section_of_site`.  In your example, it seems that this function is going to look up information on a user or person, so perhaps it would be `route=person`

So now your full url would be:

```
http://www.domain.foo/index.php?route=person&firstname=joseph&surname=soap&job=engineer&language=english
```

Even without a framework or controller class, you now have a route variable which you could use to include a script, or to execute a function or class function.  You have all the variables you need in $_GET, and all that is left is to do whatever data persistence work you require and return your result.